# I want to aggregate data array inside another array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to aggregate MongoDB documents which is having arrays inside of an array. my document was like the below.

```
{
  "_id": "6257e31d11a9d5231c05c084",
  "name": "Test Name 1",
  "phone": "1234567891",
  "visits": [
    {
      "_id": "6257e31d11a9d5231c05c069",
      "date": "2-7-2021",
      "samples": [
        "6257f8855197613b641d494e",
        ....
      ],
      "products_detailed": [
        "5d725cd2c4ded7bcb480eab2",
        .....

      ]
    },
    ...........
  ]
}
```

and I want to get the output line below

```
{
  "_id": "6257e31d11a9d5231c05c084",
  "name": "Test Name 1",
  "phone": "1234567891",
  "visits": [
    {
      "_id": "6257e31d11a9d5231c05c069",
      "date": "2-7-2021",
      "samples": [
        {
          "_id": "6257f8855197613b641d494e",
          "product_name": "Samor",
          "price": 250
        },
        ........
      ],
      "products_detailed": [
        {
          "_id": "5d725cd2c4ded7bcb480eab2",
          "product_name": "Pahad",
          "price": 100
        },
        ............
      ]
    },
    .........................
  ]
}
```

how can I get like this? I tried to use $lookup & group to get the output, but I am not getting the output as required me.

Comment: Please provide sample data. If your expected output is using data that is taken from more than one collection, please provide the relevant collections, each with sample data.

Comment: Hello nimrod serok, i am trying to get data from two other collections. my main collection contains nested array of objects, and needs to aggregate the data from all the collections. following is the sample data.  Samples Collection: `[{"_id": "6257f8855197613b641d494e", "product_name": "Samor",  "price": 250}, {"_id": "6257f8855197613b641d498d", "product_name": "Johed",  "price": 180}, .....]` and Product Detailed collection: `[{ "_id": "5d725cd2c4ded7bcb480eab2", "product_name": "Pahad",  "price": 100  }, { "_id": "5d725cd2c4ded7bcb480edc8", "product_name": "Morsa",  "price": 180  },...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a list of visits on each document, one way to go is to `$unwind` and then `$group` at the end, like this:

```
db.Main.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$visits"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Samples",
      "localField": "visits.samples",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "samples"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Product Detailed",
      "localField": "visits.products_detailed",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "products_detailed"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      phone: 1,
      "visits._id": 1,
      "visits.date": 1,
      "visits.products_detailed": "$products_detailed",
      "visits.samples": "$samples"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 0,
      name: {$first: "$name"},
      visits: {$push: "$visits"}
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bz5y20_xdOn), on your data sample it will return:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "name": "Test Name 1",
    "visits": [
      {
        "_id": "6257e31d11a9d5231c05c069",
        "date": "2-7-2021",
        "products_detailed": [
          {
            "_id": "5d725cd2c4ded7bcb480eab2",
            "price": 100,
            "product_name": "Pahad"
          }
        ],
        "samples": [
          {
            "_id": "6257f8855197613b641d494e",
            "price": 250,
            "product_name": "Samor"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```